# AngularJS Resolve Promise. Redirect if promise is rejected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase-authentication

A little back story.

- I have public pages, not restricted
- I have private pages, restricted that require login.
- I am using Firebase Authentication for the login.

I have my `$routeProvider` set up in my `.config()` of my main `.module()` My restricted paths look like the following.

```
.when('/admin', {
            controller: 'adminCtrl as admin',
            templateUrl: 'pages/admin/dashboard.tpl.html',
            resolve: {
                "currentAuth": ["$firebaseAuth", function($firebaseAuth) {
                    //$requireAuth returns a promise if authenticated, rejects if not
                    var ref = new Firebase(fbUrl);
                    var authObj = $firebaseAuth(ref);

                    return authObj.$requireAuth();
                }]
            }
        })
```

My question is about the resolve specifically, I am assuming it is working correctly because I am not seeing the `templateUrl` on my browser. (I know this for a fact, I removed the return and placed `return true` and my templateUrl appeared)

So right now, this promise in the resolve is getting rejected. Since I am not a logged in user.

My question is, how would I either a. send `$routeProvider` to my `.otherwise` route or b. place a redirect in the resolve if the promise is rejected.

Basically, If the user is not logged in, I want them sent back to the home page. Right now the browser is just showing a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research (I realize now I needed to dig more, sorry won't happen again.)

I have found a solution by adding `.run()` to my application.

```
.run(function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function(event, current, previous, eventObj) {
        console.log(eventObj);
        if (eventObj === 'AUTH_REQUIRED') {
            $location.path("/");
        }
    });
})
```

This grabs my routeChangeError and redirects when I have the error of AUTH_REQUIRED.

Simple.